# Closing vs migrating a question (or what does migration mean?)

Tags: discussion, closing, migration, close-reasons

According to the [FAQ of meta](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/faq), users with 500 rep can “vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions.”  Since my rep is below 500, I do not know what exactly means by “migrate” a question.  However, I have seen a question on meta.stackoverflow.com which was migrated from stackoverflow.com, and I assumed that it was possible to migrate a question between the parent site and the meta site.

[This question](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324/what-is-the-number-of-problems-in-p-what-about-np-closed) had been somehow posted on meta instead of the parent site.  I had thought that it should be migrated to the parent site, but it was closed instead.  Why wasn’t it migrated to the parent site?

Comment: I have 500+ rep, I do not see an option to migrate questions here or on the parent site.

Comment: @Robin: Thanks for the answer.  See my comment on Suresh’s answer for how to vote to migrate a question from parent to meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I have super-awesome moderator powers, I can tell you that I can't do it either. I think migration is something that is planned for the SE 2.0 sites, but they are all in beta right now. In any case, I don't think there's any intention to allow migration from meta to parent. It's possible that eventually it might be permissible to migrate from one site to another, but in that case I can't imagine individual site moderators having the ability to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  It seems that it is possible to vote to migrate a question from parent to meta (by choosing “close” and “belongs on meta” as a reason) but that it is not possible to migrate in the other direction.  I realized that I could try this on my own questions because I had rep ≥ 250 only after seeing your and Robin’s answers.  I should have noticed it before asking this question!

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that each *.sx site would have a short list of sites that they can migrate to, just as at present questions on SO, SU, and SF can be migrated to each other and to their own meta site.

For each *.sx site, this list of sites would include the meta of each site, and it would be reasonable for SO and math.sx to be on the list for us.  At present this is unimplemented.

This was explained somewhere on meta.SO rather some time ago.

Comment: Thank you for the related information.

Comment: So in the future we could have the option to migrate to and from MO for example, assuming they want to do so too?

Comment: only if they migrate to 2.0 - not clear if they want to.